# Change size & spacing of UWP RatingControl

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

There's a new [RatingControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.ratingcontrol) in UWP that allows you to show ratings as a series of stars. I was wondering how I can change the size of the stars and also the spacing between them.

FontSize does not work like it did on the Telerik version for UWP.

I hope this is possible without restyling the whole control. For example, [Microsoft explicitly states "Spacing customization" as a feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/rating):

> The rating control has many additional features which can be used. Details for using these features can be found in our MSDN reference documentation. Here is a non-comprehensive list of additional functionality:
>
> - Great long list performance
> - Compact sizing for tight UI scenarios
> - Continuous value fill and rating
> - Spacing customization
> - Disable growth animations
> - Customization of the number of stars

Comment: you actually have to retemplate the control which means restyle it maybe using blend or directly xaml if you are comfortable with that.

Comment: bummer, I was hoping this wouldn't be necessary. Especially since Microsoft lists "Spacing customization" as a feature (see updated question).

Comment: I am not sure wht the spacing here means , maybe space between the stars? but it certainly doesnt refer to size of the stars.

Comment: spacing alone would definitely help

Comment: I saw the docs I cnt find a property which has "space" in it so I am guessing the docs are misleading in that respect, I suggest you should give feedback on the docs page so that they can fix this confusion, if you dont know how to give feedback on docs please do let me know I will be happy to guide you.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to edit the control template, a quick way is to use `ViewBox` container to host the `RatingControl`, you can resize the `RatingControl` by resizing the `ViewBox`.

```
<ViewBox Width="" Height="">
    <RatingControl .../>
</ViewBox>
```

Comment: yes this seems a good option as well, a ViewBox will actually sort of magnify your whole controls, so if that works for u this is the simplest and safe option to use @Thomas