# How can i set the width and height of the rating star in uwp?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have added a rating control in xaml but i don't know how to set it's width and height.Already it has the property width and height but it actually setting the width and height of the border around it.

```
  <RatingControl x:Name="rating control" width="200" height="200">
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RatingControlSelectedForeground" Color="Red" />
  </RatingControl>
```

Comment: There are two options, [use a ViewBox as the container to host the RatingControl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51823440/815938); or edit the `ControlTemplate` of the `RatingControl` in Visual Studio.